# How to map URL path to physical path in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, url, path

I have an *ImageUpload* folder in the root of my ASP.NET MVC website, running on Windows and hosted on AWS.

When displaying the images, I need something like this:

```
<img src="/ImageUpload/MyImage.jpg" alt="">
```

When uploading images, I need a physical path...

```
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\\MyWebsiteRoot\\ImageUpload",  MyImage.jpg);
file.SaveAs(fullPath);
```

I want to put the path in my web.Config:

```
<!-- if I use a url path, the save won't work -->
<add key="ImageUploadPath" value="/ImageUpload"></add>

<!-- if I use physical path, the display won't work -->
<add key="ImageUploadPath" value="C:\\MyWebsiteRoot\\ImageUpload"></add>
```

Is it possible to define *ImageUpload* path in the Web.Config in a manner that it can be used both as a physical path and url path? Or do I need to define 2 different variables in my Web.Config?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: did u try  : <img src="~/ImageUpload/MyImage.jpg" alt=" "> ?

with using , "~/" IIS express resolves the physical path

Comment: I want to define ImageUpload path in my WebConfg. How can I use it both as a physical path and url path?

Comment: You should not use the physical directory location for image src. just use the relative url like what you did.

Comment: @Shyju, thanks. so if I use: /ImageUpload, how would the file.SaveAs() would know where is the physical location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store your image folder (which is present in your app root) name in the app settings and use that for saving and rendering the images

```
<add key="ImageUploadPath" value="ImageUpload"></add>
```

and when you save the uploaded file, read this value and use that to build the path. You can create a string like `"~/ImageUploadPath"` and pass that to `Server.MapPath` method, which will return the physical file path corresponding to the virtual path you passed to it.

```
var fileName = "yourImageFileName.jpg";
var directory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"];
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/" + directory), fileName);
model.Image.SaveAs(path);
```

When rendering the image, use the same approach to read the directory name and render the  image `src` value.

For example,

```
public ActionResult Profile(int userId)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
    var vm = new UserProfileVm { FirstName = user.FirstName , Id = user.Id };
    vm.ProfileImage = GetImagePath(vm.ImagePath);
    return View(vm);
}
private string GetImagePath(string imageName)
{
   return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUploadPath"] + "/" + imageName;
}
```

and in your view,

```
@model UserProfileVm
<img src="~/@Model.ProfileImage" alt="@Model.FirstName" />
```